# Calculate depth of water based on shadow size

Tags: geometry

I just saw the below image on the Facebook and wanted to see how I could calculate the depth of the water based on the image itself. Also, how accurate would this calculation be? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm new to this forum and didn't know what to tag. Please edit the tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not enough information to calculate the depth.

The *size* of the (image of the) shadow is about the same as the size of the (image of the) object casting it, so that tells us nothing. (This ignores perspectivic effects, which depends on camera position and other parameters that we have no chance of estimating here anyway).

We'd have better hope of deriving something from the *position* of the shadow relative to the floating sunbather on the image, but there's still no luck there, because we don't have any good information about the exact position of the sun then the photo was taken -- nor about which angle the image was taken from. Either of these lacks would make it imposible to conclude anything.

Comment: The fact that the shadow is about the same size suggests that the sun is (roughly) above. Perhaps just measuring the corner-to-corner distance would give a rough estimate?

Comment: Thank you. Some guy said that he has calculated this and my initial thought was the same (not exactly the same of course) as your answer, but since I'm not a "math guy", I thought maybe I was wrong.